# Android Jetpack Compose set modifier properties as percentage of device width or height

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to be able to set all Modifier properties as percentage of the known device width or height. The idea is that there is no need to support different screen sizes for all phones - small, medium or big phones. All phones should have the same composable size related to the current device width or height. And we should only implement different screen sizes for `tablets` or `landscape mode`.

I know that for width, height we can use `.fillMaxWidth(0.9f)`, and set float value [from = 0.0, to = 1.0] that matches the Constraints.maxWidth multiply by the fraction we specify.

I want to specify the Modifier attributes similar to dp, sp, but instead use something like dw(device width) and dh(device height).

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is simple implementation using `androidx.window:window:1.0.0` library to get the actual device width and height and converts it to [Dp](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/unit/Dp). Use the `dw,dh` when you want the min side to always match the width and the maximum side to match the height. Or use `adw,adh` when you want the width and height to change depending on device rotation: landscape or portrait mode.

***[You can find the source code here](https://github.com/slaviboy/JetpackComposePercentageUnits)***

To use the library just include the dependency

```
implementation 'com.github.slaviboy:JetpackComposePercentageUnits:1.0.0'
```

Now we can set the `offset, padding, width, height, border, font size...` to be scaled according to the device width or height.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
 
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // init device width and height
        initSize() 

        setContent { 
    
            // your UI here
        Text(
            text = "Hello",
            fontSize = 0.04.sh,
            color = Color.Green, 
            modifier = Modifier
                .offset(x = 0.07.dw, y = 0.2.dh)
                .border(
                    width = 0.01.dw,
                    color = Color.Red,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(0.05.dw)
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Now everything is scaled according to the device width or height and the Composable will match every phone size.

[image]

Comment: Just wanted to say that app looks great!